# Handling JPA commit exceptions in a layered approach

Tags: java, jpa, exception, dao

In our app, these are the layers used:

```
Rest Service Endpoint Layer --> Business Layer --> DAO --> ORM
```

Now, each layer translates its exceptions appropriately and sends them to the next layer. For example, `DAO Layer` creates a `DaoException` and throws to `Business Layer`, `Bussiness Layer` translates this to `BusinessException` which throws it to `RestService Layer` where it is handled by a cxf mapper (okay, not really in RestServiceLayer).

We have put `@Transactional` on the methods of `Business Layer`. So, if an exception happens at commit, the `exception` will be fist seen only in the `Rest Service Endpoint Layer`. Now, I will have to check for *transaction commit related exceptions(eg. `RollBackException etc.`)* in the topmost layer (`Rest Service Endpoint Layer`), which would kind of defeat the purpose of each layer translating the exceptions for the next layer.

What would be a good way of dealing with this situation? Should I not translate exceptions at all and handle all of them only on the topmost layer?

Answer (score 0):

Write an annotation-driven AOP point-cut on exception thrown and have that translate if you really want to translate and apply the annotation to your business layer. But I would also recommend against translating - what are you gaining by having the translation?

Comment: I have seen posts on SO and otherwise which say that it is meaningful to translate exceptions from one layer to the other which would leave only a limited set of relevant exceptions for the subsequent layer. I might have missed some fundamental point though. A suggestion like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256255/handling-dao-exceptions-in-service-layer)

Comment: Also, I am actually not using @ Transactional but @ MyTransactional (because I am not using JPA but a custom wrapper written by one of the teams in my company. They don't support @Transactional yet) which is already AOP point-cut and I am throwing an exception from there which is to be handled somewhere consistently in accordance with the rest of the exception handling.

Comment: I guess it goes to your philosophy of exceptions. An exception should not be something that one can "recover" from. I.e., don't transmit valid business cases via exception. I use exceptions only to get out of whatever I was trying and abort the operation and convey to the caller that whatever you tried failed and pass enough information to debug/troubleshoot/fix etc. Think every exception is an unchecked exception. So why do I care what the exception was. PersistentException vs. 10 flavors of actual Hibernate/JPA exceptions. How am I handling it differently?

Comment: I would agree to what you are saying but I think I will find it really difficult convincing people in my org to break from the philosophy that is being practiced :-|